# What is a set of seven numbers that have a mean median mode and range of 10?

Tags: average, means, median

I have to answer this question for my homework and I have spent hours trying to research it but I haven't come across an answer. I thought it may be 10 but then I realised that it would mean that the range was zero and I need them all to be ten.

Comment: hint:  so, they can't all be $10$ because of the range but most of them can be $10$

Comment: $5,10-b,10-a,10,10+a,10+b,15$. (here $0\le a \le b \le 5$).

Comment: @Oleg567 Mode is also $10$ so atleast one more $10$ is required

Comment: @A False Name: yes, thanks; then $a=0$ and $0\le b\le5$.

Comment: 5,10,10,10,10,10,15

Answer (score 2):

You can first start with 7 10s. $$10,10,10,10,10,10,10$$ Now, to make the range 10 as well, the greatest and least value must differ by 10. In other words, you want a set of two numbers that have a mean of 10, but a range of 10. We see that $5,15$ works. So we combine that set with another set of 5 10s. $$5,10,10,10,10,10,15$$ If we have another set with a range of 10, for example $4,14$, we need another value to balance the drop in the mean. We can add a 12 to make $$4,10,10,10,10,12,14$$